# How do I stop Ubuntu from overriding my setxkbmap settings?

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have put the following in my .profile:

```
rm -f executed.log
echo ".profile starting" >> executed.log
if [ `whoami` != "root" ] 
    then 
    setxkbmap -v >> executed.log
    setxkbmap -layout "us" -variant "altgr-intl" -option "ctrl:nocaps"
    echo "setxkbmap executed" >> executed.log
    setxkbmap -v >> executed.log
fi

echo ".profile finished" >> executed.log
```

After startup the following log is written:

```
[22:02:21][giorgio@Desmond:~]$ cat executed.log 
.profile starting
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(altgr-intl)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
setxkbmap executed
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(altgr-intl)+inet(evdev)+ctrl(nocaps)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
.profile finished
```

But after a graphical login I get:

```
[22:02:23][giorgio@Desmond:~]$ setxkbmap -v
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
```

It seems Unity is overriding my settings, probably with the indicator keyboard applet or something similar. How do I disable it so that I can use my .profile settings?

Comment: If you add your settings after unity changes things do they stick?

Comment: Yes, they do until the next reboot.

Answer (score 2):

> updated

```
rm -f executed.log
echo ".profile starting" >> executed.log
if [ $(whoami) != "root" ] 
then 
  echo "$(setxkbmap -v)">> executed.log
  echo "$(setxkbmap -layout "us" -variant "altgr-intl" -option "ctrl:nocaps")"
  echo "setxkbmap executed" >> executed.log
  echo "$(setxkbmap -v)">> executed.log
fi
```

check for small correction. Check for reverse quote.

When you login in GUI. Its taking setxkbmap as a string. You have to use reverse quote to tell treat those characters as a command.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. The reverse quotes merely makes the shell try to execute the output of "setxkbmap -v", which is full of syntax errors. As you can see from my `cat executed.log`, setxkbmap is already being executed, but something overwrites its configuration after .profile.

Comment: Check for updated answer. Its working. I just missed echo before reverse quotes.

Comment: Edited to replace reverse quotes, which were not shown correctly, by $()